# How can i shows added person ? JQuery after inserting to db

Tags: jquery

I basically insert person to my db and use below code.After inserting db if(response==ok)

it adds person to db. However, i have to show the added person. If i use reload it send the main page. What's your suggestion for that?

```
function AddData(par){

    var artistName =  $("input[name='"+par+"']").attr('id') + '-'+$("input[name='"+par+"']").val();

   $.post('/json/management/AddDataAjax2', 
    {
       "artistName": artistName
    },
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if(response =='ok')
             alert("Başarıyla eklendi");
         else{
             alert("Sanatçı bulunamadı, yönlendiriliyorsunuz");
             window.location.replace("http://www.sinemalar.com/management/artistAddEditRemove/");
         }
});
}
```

Comment: Uhm... add code that shows the person, instead of `alert`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ .
Your response can be anything, such as HTML, JSON...

Comment: so send that name as response.